# Reload the page after clicking a form button in IE

Tags: javascript, html, django

I have a problem with my web site.
I have a button that displays the form and the problem is that on IE and on the edge when I click this button it shows me the form but refreshed the page automatically after the click.

I do not know how to solve this problem. Can you help me please ?

Here is my code html :

```
    <div class="col-xs-3" id="div6">
        <div style="text-align: center; color: #333; font-weight:bold;">Actualité</div>
        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        {% if request.user.is_staff %}
        <form action="#modification">
            <div style="text-align: center;">
                <button type="submit" id="modifier" class="btn btn-primary">Modifier l'actu</button>
            </div>
        </form>
        <form action="#modification" id="formActu" style="display: none" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div id="modification"></div>
            <div style="text-align: center;">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="valider" style="margin-top: 1%;">Valider</button>
            </div>
        </form>
        {% endif %}
        {% endif %}
        {% if not actu %}
        <div id="messageNonActu" style="margin-top: 5%;">Pas d'actualité pour le moment !</div>
        {% endif %}
        {% for actuCommentaire in actu %}
        <div id="commentaireActu" style="margin-top: 5%;">{{actuCommentaire.commentaire}}</div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
```

Here is my script :

```
            $(document).ready(function(){
            var compteur = 0;

            $('#modifier').click(function(){
                if(compteur === 0){
                    $('#modification').append('{% for field in form %}<label class="my_class" for="{{ field.name|escapejs }}">{{ field.label|escapejs }} :</label>{{ field|escapejs }}{% endfor %}');
                    $('#formActu').show()
                    $('#exampleTextarea').css({resize: 'none'});
                    $('#commentaireActu').hide();
                    $('#messageNonActu').hide();
                    $('#modifier').removeClass('btn btn-primary').addClass('btn btn-danger');
                    $('#modifier').html("Annuler la modif");
                    compteur++;
                }else{
                    if($('#formActu').is(':visible')){
                        $('#formActu').hide();
                        $('#commentaireActu').show();
                        $('#modifier').removeClass('btn btn-danger').addClass('btn btn-primary');
                        $('#modifier').html("Modifier l'actu");
                    }else{
                        $('#commentaireActu').hide();
                        $('#formActu').show();
                        $('#modifier').removeClass('btn btn-primary').addClass('btn btn-danger');
                        $('#modifier').html("Annuler la modif");
                    }
                }
            });
        });
```

[Image 1 with just button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P2rXk.png)

After clicking I have a preview of the second image but it refreshed the page in less than a second after clicking on the button

[Image 2 with form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLw7N.png)

Then I get the visual of the first image directly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this and check:(Just **return false** from the end of method because IE considers button click as submit that's why your page reloads)

$('#modifier').click(function(){

//your logic

```
 return false;
```

}

Comment: I thank you it works. Thank you very much you just saved my life :)